# How can I access a property that has the same name as class but different event code?

Tags: applescript

When an application uses the same name for a class and a property but different event codes, and I try to use the property in an object specifier, AppleScript interprets the identifier as the class rather than the property. For example:

```
tell application "Mail"
    header of first rule condition of first rule
end
```

This results in the error:

> Mail got an error: Can’t get header of rule condition 1 of rule 1.

The styling of `header` in AppleScript Editor (blue italics) suggests it's a class name rather than a property. How can I specify the identifier is a property and resolve this naming collision explicitly?

I'm running OS X 10.6.8 and Mail.app 4.5.

#### Non-working solution

In "[Applescript: The Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596102119)", Matt Neuberg suggests that `its` may be used:

> The keyword `it` is needed when an application has defined a property with the same name as a class. [...] Saying `its` disambiguates.

However, this doesn't resolve the issue in my sample code above. After adding `its`, `header` is still styled as a class and the script results in the same error.

```
tell application "Mail"
    its header of first rule condition of first rule
end
```

Applying the example from § 20.8.3. "Properties with Eponymous Classes" has the same result.

```
tell application "Mail"
    tell first rule
        tell first rule condition
            get its header
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

#### Background

I'm attempting to write an AppleScript to extend Mail.app's rule conditions to support pattern matching. Some rule conditions in one of these extended rules are to contain information for the script, such as the pattern to match and the action to take if the pattern matches, rather than being conditions that Mail should match. I'd like to make use the `header` property for these rule conditions.

Alternative ways of extending rules to allow for pattern matching are fine but not requested. I'd still like the particular question answered, since the issue can arise in cases other than this particular usage.

Answer (score 3):

Edit:  I was able to get it to fail as you described by doing some rearranging.  The Script Editor does seem to lock in to whatever its first guess was, so one solution would be to use **run script** to use the raw class at run time, for example:

```
tell application "Mail"
    header of (get properties of first rule condition of first rule) -- fails
end tell

set myHeader to (run script "tell application \"Mail\"
    return «class rhed» of (get properties of first rule condition of first rule)
end tell")
myHeader --> success
```

Comment: That causes the identifier to be interpreted as a variable, which doesn't get me the `header` property. As for not using `header` (which isn't a reserved word), I have no choice in the matter, since it's Mail.app that defines it.

Comment: The term "header" would be reserved when targeting Mail.app.  Use of the term "it" refers to the current target (which in your snippets is already Mail).  If you are talking about referring to a rule condition header vs a message header, you just need to target the appropriate object.  I guess I am still not understanding the question, since your snippets work for me.

Comment: It's not a matter of targeting the appropriate object. I find the property `header` of rule conditions is inaccessible, apparently due to the different event codes used. RE: code working for you. What OS and version of Mail.app are you using?

Comment: I'm running Mail v5.1 in Lion 10.7.2.  You might try getting the properties incrementally - for example get the rules, then the rule conditions of some rule, then the headers of that, etc, to see if something is missing.  You will still need to target Mail in your handlers to use its properties.

Comment: "reserved" usually means [keywords](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/conceptual/ASLR_lexical_conventions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH214-SW7), though it's not an official term, so I can see how you use it differently. In this case, however, I'm not trying to use an identifier that clashes with one of Mail.app's, I'm trying to use the identifier that Mail.app supplies; in your parlance, I'm trying to use the actual reserved term.

Comment: I bet Mail.app 5.1 uses the same event code for the `header` property of rule conditions as it does elsewhere (mhdr), so there's no problem with interpreting the identifier. Try both raw codes ("mhdr" and "rhed") and see if the former works while the latter fails. Getting properties incrementally won't help, as I've already identified which property is problematic (there's no issue with getting rule conditions).

Comment: Mail 5.1 uses the same event codes.  Either one worked for me, but I was able to get it to fail by rearranging some terms, so I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

From a comment on ["Applescript et Mail.app, bug ou c'est moi"](http://www.cynicalturtle.net/kame/index.php/2005/02/07/948-applescript-et-mailapp-bug-ou-c-est-moi), the `header` property has a different event code than the class ("rhed" for the property, "mhdr" for the class). This appears to be both the actual cause of the error (`header` compiles to `«class mhdr»`) and offers a potential solution: you can use a raw event code designator to get the property in this particular case.

```
tell application "Mail"
    «property rhed» of first rule condition of first rule
end
```

However, the first time you save the script, the raw code gets replaced by the name, and the second time you save the name is re-interpreted as a class rather than a property, requiring you to correct every occurrence of the property name each time you save. The amount of work to be done can be reduced by defining a handler to get the property outside of a block where Mail.app's terms are being used.

```
on hdr(rc)
    return «property rhed» of rc
end hdr
tell application "Mail"
    my hdr(first rule condition of first rule)
end
```

By defining the handler in a location where Mail.app's terms aren't being used, the raw code won't be replaced by an identifier.

This only partly solves the save-edit issue, as each separate property requires its own handler and (what's worse) handlers don't appear to work in [filter forms](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_reference_forms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH4g-BAJJHEFE) (though loops could be used instead). As such, I cannot accept this answer and would appreciate a full solution, if someone can find one. As an example, the following

```
on hdr(rc)
    return «property rhed» of rc
end hdr
tell application "Mail"
    every rule condition of first rule where my hdr(it) is not ""
end
```

results in:

> error "Mail got an error: Can’t get header." number -1728 from header

Answer (score 0):

Use **rule condition tell block** and the keyword **its** to get the header.

```
tell application "Mail" to tell rule condition 1 of rule 1
    return its header 
end tell
```